# Eevee render cuts off back drop

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image]
[image]
I know it has something to do with screen space refraction but I cant find it with a few google searches.

Behind this window is a png backdrop with alpha mask and a plane with an emission shader.

When the camera slide along the backdrop fades grey.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to turn on overscan in the Properties tab>render>film.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thanks!